# Kotlin rotateAnimation is not working. Nothing is happening when the spinBtn is clicked

Tags: kotlin, animation

***I am trying to create af spinningWheel animation with my imageView spinning once the button is pressed. I found a youtube video with some java code i converted into kotlin. With the code below nothing happens when the button is pushed. I have used the rotateAnimation class and some calculations in the GameViewModel thus far, and call the spin() in the GameFragment class' onCreateView().

The code below are the two classes i use for the rotateAnimation but it doesn't seem to work. I am not sure which part is the problem. Does anyone know?***

class GameViewModel : ViewModel() {

```
private val fields = arrayOf("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")
private val fieldDegrees = IntArray(fields.size)
private var degree = 0
var isSpinning = false


fun getDegreesForSectors(){
    val oneFieldsDegrees = 360/fields.size
    for (i in fields.indices){
        fieldDegrees[i] = (i+1) * oneFieldsDegrees
    }
}


fun spin(imageView: ImageView){
    isSpinning = true
    degree = (0..fields.size).random()

    val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(0.toFloat(),
        (360 * fields.size + fieldDegrees[degree]).toFloat(),
        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f)

    rotateAnimation.setDuration(3600)
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true)
    rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
    rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener{

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {}

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
            isSpinning = false
        }
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}

    })
    imageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
}
```

}

class GameFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var gameViewModel: GameViewModel
private var _binding: GameFragmentBinding? = null

// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    gameViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(GameViewModel::class.java)


    val spinBtn: Button? = view?.findViewById(R.id.spinBtn)
    val wheelImage: ImageView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.Spinning_Wheel)
    gameViewModel.getDegreesForSectors()
    spinBtn?.setOnClickListener() {
        if (!gameViewModel.isSpinning) {
            gameViewModel.spin(wheelImage!!)
        }
    }


  _binding = GameFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
  val root: View = binding.root
  return root



}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

}

Comment: First thing is that view model isn't the right place to put your animation logic. You app might crash on a configuration change.

Comment: And why you are using view binding together with findViewById???

Comment: `val spinBtn: Button? = view?.findViewById(R.id.spinBtn)` Do you have a `view` here? I believe it would be just `null`. Check it once

Comment: Should the animation logic go in the GameFragment then and if so what kind of stuff is the viewModel used for? I made the ID for the button spinBTN

Comment: That logic seems fine in the view model, it's not holding a reference to the ``ImageView`` - it's just a utility function that applies an animation to the object passed in. It's kinda the wrong place for it - it's UI stuff so it should be in the view (Fragment) - and that ``isSpinning`` state will be invalid if the view is destroyed (e.g. rotating the device), but it shouldn't crash anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing fragment `view` inside onCreateView(). This will return null since nothing has been inflated yet.
Use the binding variable to access the views.

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    gameViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(GameViewModel::class.java)

    _binding = GameFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    gameViewModel.getDegreesForSectors()
    binding.spinBtn.setOnClickListener() {
        if (!gameViewModel.isSpinning) {
            gameViewModel.spin(binding.spinningWheel)
        }
    }

  return binding.root
}
```

Comment: This was one issue that I noticed. If this doesn't fix your problem, you can comment below.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: My mistake, Doesn't crash but Stil doesn't do anything when the button is pressed.

Comment: Wait!! it's wworking!! thank you Arpit